# How to add caption to a figure inside of table

Tags: tables, captions

I'd like to add a caption to a figure in a table. If I use `\begin{figure}...\caption{caption} \end{figure}`, I get a compilation error. Could anyone help me figure out how to fix this.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title[]{Beamer title}
\author[]{Author name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title }
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            %\begin{figure}
               \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{sample.jpg}
            %    \caption{Caption of figure} 
            %\end{figure} 
        \end{tabular} 
        &
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\footnotesize 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
                    \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
                    \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
                \end{itemize}
            }
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also put tabulars inside a figure environment, especially with no caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}` within a block environment (like `minipage`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer} 

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize]{caption}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title }
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \captionof{figure}{Caption of figure} 
    \end{minipage} 
    &
      \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\footnotesize 
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
        \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
        \item Some explanation about figure with more than one lines. 
      \end{itemize}
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that using "floats" within a presentation doesn't have the same impact/referencing capacity that it would in an article. There's no real way for folks viewing a presentation to go around and find figures or tables again. It's better to give an appropriate caption that is understandable within the inclusion of the typical "Figure:" or "Table:" reference with the figure.